# Лихой джигит отбрасывает повод или всё ж таки поводья?

Tags: синонимы

> Нимфеум виллы . Источник, который останавливает протяжённую ось главной
>   подъездной аллеи, что длится несколько километров. Это фонтан, у
>   которого оказываешься, если **сто миль по прямой дал, спешился с
>   лошади у парадного крыльца, отбросил повод, взбежал на крыльцо, прошёл
>   насквозь парадную залу дома и вышел на задний двор**. И... и ведь до
>   сих пор тут хозяевам неплохо. В жаркий сезон в тени расставлены
>   шезлонги.

Или в данном случае именно "повод", потому что лихач успел спешиться?

Comment: Такой (как видно тут и по прочим фрагментам) инфостиль задан (неудачно, IMNSHO) умышленно или просто автор по другому не умеет?

Comment: Автор - искусствовед и актёр. Действительно, *как он дышит, так и пишет, / Не стараясь угодить...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "Повод" и "поводья" - практические синонимы, у них нет ситуативной привязки "лихач успел спешиться" в русском русском языке.
- Если судить по применимости в источниках 19 века (см. С. П. Урусов "Верховая езда", к примеру), то "повод" является скорее профессионализмом для всех, связанных с верховой ездой, а "поводья" - у лошади как транспортного движка.

Так что в контексте, как мне кацца, - "повод". И внутренний граммар-наци и читатель классической литературы не возражает.